# Python Django error 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, django

I am very new in Python and Django.I am trying to resize my images for one of my image based website.I have a view which actually rendering all the images and those images are re sizing using a base width as follow..

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageEnhance

def showphoto(request,template = 'base.html',page_template = 'photo/showphoto.html'):
    basewidth = 300

    photos = Photo.objects.order_by('-uploaded_time')
    img = Image.open(photos)
    wpercent = (basewidth/float(img.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
    img = img.resize((basewidth,hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    photo_list=img.save(photos)


    context = {}
    context.update({
    'photo_list': photo_list,
    'page_template': page_template,
    })

    if request.is_ajax():
        template = page_template
    return render_to_response(template,context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but i am facing an error somethin like that..

```
 AttributeError at /showphoto/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'read'
```

and this is my Photo model..

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos', blank=False,null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    uploaded_time = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 80 , blank = False , null = True)
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length = 200 , blank = False , null = True)
    image_id = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    Certified = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    approved_by = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    total_download = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    watermarked_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'temp', blank=True,null=True)
```

now whats the problem,please take a close look in my code.

Comment: Photo.objects.order_by('-uploaded_time') return QuerySet(list of Photo ) and img = Image.open(photos) try to open a QuerySet of Photo

Comment: `Image.open` expects the path to an image file, not a queryset. Hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

First, since you are new to Python and Django, better to start off with [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/overview.html) instead of Pil, as it is essentially unmaintained and Pillow is the preferred library since Django 1.6.

Secondly, resizing your images in a view is not the preferred way to do it. Besides, you are resizing your images each time. A more common approach is to use a templatetag like [sorl-thumbnail](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

As for the specific error, as Platinum Azure said, you are passing a queryset instance to a function that expects a file object or a path. If you want to go on with your approach you can iterate over your queryset (not tested!):

```
# Outside your view
def resize_photo(photo):
    img = Image.open(photo)
    wpercent = (basewidth/float(img.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
    img.resize((basewidth,hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save()        
    return img

# In your view
photo_list = [resize_photo(p.photo) for p in photos]
```

Comment: i have used your code pattern,but still it showing the same error that i have faced before that is **Photo object has no attribute 'read' at Image.open(photo) **

Comment: Yes, you should use the field used to save the actual photo path in your `Photo` model. Can you show that to us?

Comment: i have updated my post.see i have added my photo model.

Comment: now i am facing this error "save() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)" after using your updated answer.I am sorry,i am still a novice.

Comment: True. You have to specify a file name and path for the saved thumbnail. This is up to you to find a convention to name it. Or you can make your life easier and use sorl-thumbnail as I suggested.

Comment: sorl-thunbnail not going to fulfill my requirement, i am trying to resize images according to the base width,that each image will maintain its own shape.

Comment: If you need to resize saving the aspect ratio, just omit the size you want to scale. In your case `{% thumbnail photo "300" as im %}`: http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/template.html#thumbnail

Comment: its useful and i am going to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're treating a queryset of images as a single image. You might need to iterate over your results and process the images one at a time.

The error comes from the fact that you're treating the queryset as a file-like object by sending it to `Image.open()`. It's only when you try to get information about the image that the library tries to read the "file", only to discover it's not a for after all since it doesn't implement the `read` method.